# Как преобразовать запрос из shell MongoDB в Jongo?

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

У меня есть (работающий в shell) запрос к MongoDB:

```
db.stores.aggregate([ { $unwind: "$listProducts" }, { $match : { "listProducts.productPrice" : { $ne : 0 } } }, { $group : { _id : { storeName : "$storeName", }, MAX_Products : { $max : "$listProducts.productPrice" } } } ])
```

Как его можно написать в Jongo?
Конечно, я прочитал все в http://jongo.org

Я написал, по аналогии, также как там в примере с "Aggregation Framework"

```
Aggregate.ResultsIterator max = stores.aggregate("{$unwind:{$listProducts}") .and("{$match:{$listProducts.productPrice {$ne : 0 }}") .and("{$group:{$storeName}") .and("{$max:{$listProducts.productPrice}") .as(Store.class);
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot parse query: {$unwind:{$listProducts}

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Будьте добры, напишите, какая более подробная информация необходима, для уточнения этого вопроса?
Есть запрос, написанный в shell MongoDB (приводится), как можно ЭТОТ ЖЕ запрос преобразовать в запрос Jongo.
Не знаю, что тут добавить?